# Producer & Consumer is not printing answer in order

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

I am trying to write produce and consumer that should print output in below order

```
consumer 1
produce 1
consumer 2
produce 2
```

But it's not giving outputs in order. To achieve order when using synchronized keyword, it's not printing even any output.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

 public class ProducerAndCosumer {


ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue ;

public ProducerAndCosumer(int capacity) {
    this.blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer>(capacity);
}


public synchronized void consume(int data) {
    System.out.println(" consumer " + data);
    blockingQueue.offer(data);
}
public synchronized int produce() throws InterruptedException {
    int data = blockingQueue.take();
    System.out.println(" produce " + data);
    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    ProducerAndCosumer pc = new ProducerAndCosumer(10);
    
    
    Runnable run1 = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(" Entered consumer runner ");
            IntStream.range(1, 20).forEach(pc::consume);
        }
    };
     new Thread(run1).start();
     
     Runnable run2 = new Runnable() {
         
         @Override
         public void run() {
             System.out.println(" Entered producer runner ");
             try {
                 for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
                     pc.produce();
                 }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
     };
     new Thread(run2).start();
  }
```

}

Please, suggest how can I resolve it. And one more question can we achieve it without wait and notify.

Comment: There are probably 1000s of examples out there. Please research before posting. I created a paste for you anyways: https://pastebin.com/raw/75naN0UH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code, you have the race condition problem. You should provide concurrent access to your `ArrayBlockingQueue`. One of a lot of possible variants is the next example(with two semaphores):

```
 public class ProducerAndConsumer {

    private final ArrayBlockingQueue<Integer> blockingQueue ;

    private final Semaphore semaphoreOne;

    private final Semaphore semaphoreTwo;

    public ProducerAndConsumer(int capacity) {
        this.blockingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(capacity, true);
        this.semaphoreOne = new Semaphore(1);
        this.semaphoreTwo = new Semaphore(1);
    }


    public void consume(int data) throws InterruptedException {
        semaphoreOne.acquire();
        System.out.println(" consumer " + data);
        blockingQueue.offer(data);
        semaphoreTwo.release();
    }
    public void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        semaphoreTwo.acquire();
        int data = blockingQueue.take();
        System.out.println(" produce " + data);
        semaphoreOne.release();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ProducerAndConsumer pc = new ProducerAndConsumer(10);

        Runnable run1 = () -> {
            System.out.println(" Entered consumer runner ");
            for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                try {
                    pc.consume(i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        Runnable run2 = () -> {
            System.out.println(" Entered producer runner ");
            try {
                for (int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++) {
                    pc.produce();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        };
        new Thread(run1).start();
        new Thread(run2).start();
    }
}
```

Output for this program is:

```
 Entered consumer runner 
 Entered producer runner 
 consumer 1
 produce 1
 consumer 2
 produce 2
 consumer 3
 produce 3
 consumer 4
 produce 4
 consumer 5
 produce 5
 consumer 6
 produce 6
 consumer 7
 produce 7
 consumer 8
 produce 8
 consumer 9
 produce 9
 consumer 10
 produce 10
 consumer 11
 produce 11
 consumer 12
 produce 12
 consumer 13
 produce 13
 consumer 14
 produce 14
 consumer 15
 produce 15
 consumer 16
 produce 16
 consumer 17
 produce 17
 consumer 18
 produce 18
 consumer 19
 produce 19
```

Besides, when you declare both your methods `consume` `produce` `synchronized` you will have a deadlock since both methods will try to synchronize by one monitor(object `ProducerAndConsumer`), see ThreadDump
[image]